# Why won't this F# Left Outer Join implementation compile?

Tags: linq, join, f#

I am trying to implement a function roughly equivalent to a SQL `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. The difference between this and most implementations is that it has a function parameter to decide what value is used for left values that do not have a right match, rather than automatically using `null`.  I have tried a lot of variations to make the F# compiler happy, but none of them are working.

```
let public LeftOuterJoin<'Left, 'Right, 'Key, 'Result>(
    left : seq<'Left>,
    right : seq<'Right>,
    getLeftKey : Func<'Left, 'Key>,
    getRightKey : Func<'Right, 'Key>,
    getResult : Func<'Left, 'Right, 'Result>, 
    getDefaultResult : Func<'Left, 'Result>) =

    let getGroups = Func<'Left, seq<'Right>, seq<'Result>>(fun (l, rs) ->
        let rsList = rs.ToList();
        if rsList.Any()
        then rsList |> Seq.map(fun r -> getResult.Invoke(l, r))
        else Enumerable.Repeat(getDefaultResult.Invoke(l), 1))

    left.GroupJoin(right, getLeftKey, getRightKey, getGroups)                                                        
        .SelectMany(id)
```

Right now I am getting the error *This expression was expected to have type ''Left' but here has type ''a * 'b'* at the parameters for the lambda expression in the `getGroups` definition `(l, rs)`.  I am fine with any implementation that gets the desired results, whether it uses `Func` or standard F# functions as parameters. I would prefer something idiomatic in F#, but I thought using `GroupJoin` and `SelectMany` would be easy.

Here is a working version in C#:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> LeftOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TLeft> first,
        IEnumerable<TRight> second,
        Func<TLeft, TKey> getLeftKey,
        Func<TRight, TKey> getRightKey,
        Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult> getResult,
        Func<TLeft, TResult> getDefaultResult)
    {
        IEnumerable<TResult> getGroupResults (TLeft left, IEnumerable<TRight> rights)
        {
            rights = rights.ToList();
            return rights.Any()
                ? rights.Select(r => getResult(left, r))
                : Enumerable.Repeat(getDefaultResult(left), 1);
        }

        return first
            .GroupJoin(second, getLeftKey, getRightKey, getGroupResults)
            .SelectMany(seq => seq);
    }
```

---

**Update**

This compiles and looks more idiomatic

```
let public LeftOuterJoin<'L, 'R, 'Key, 'Result>(
    left : seq<'L>,
    right : seq<'R>,
    getLeftKey : 'L -> 'Key,
    getRightKey : 'R -> 'Key,
    getResult : 'L -> 'R -> 'Result,
    getDefaultResult : 'L -> 'Result) : seq<'Result> =

    let rLookup = right.ToLookup(fun r -> getRightKey(r));
    seq {
        for l in left do
            let lKey = getLeftKey(l);
            if rLookup.Contains(lKey)
            then yield! rLookup.[lKey] |> Seq.map(getResult(l))
            else yield getDefaultResult(l)
    }
```

Comment: if that update of yours is an answer to your question, I suggest you post it as an answer. Then if you are satisfied with this as the final answer in lack of other better responses, mark it as accepted.